# Internet download manager is capturing system and drives updates?

Tags: download-manager

IDM is automatically capturing NVIDIA graphic driver updates, HP Support assistant updates, Any web browser updates (Mozilla or Chrome) , which are not supposed to be downloaded by IDM. How to stop IDM from capturing these system updates ?

Comment: What do you see that indicates this exactly?

Comment: for eg., lets say adobe update service is running in background on my pc. now when it will start downloading update from adobe server, IDM takes it over and prompts with the download dialog box, and due to this adobe update service will never be able to download its update package. since that update package is specific to adobe and it will be installed by adobe update service only thus downloading that update through IDM is of no use. And this kind of problem is being encountered by all the background apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do any of the following to disable auto download capture.

1. Open the target browser and disable/remove e.g Chrome; Open  a blank tab and type chrome://extensions/ >> Go to Internet download Manager extension and tick to disable.
2. Open the Internet download Manager program  >>. Go to Options >> General  >> Under the option " Capture downloads fron the following browsers" untick the browser that you wish to exclude fron auto capturing downloads.

I recommend you to leave at least one browser enabled, so to avoid inconveniences.

Comment: But then it wont capture my downloads from that particular browser. I just dont want IDM to capture updates, but it should capture my downloads. and IDM is not only capturing browser updates, it is also capturing software updates like adobe updates, windows updates etc which should be downloaded by their respective softwares only. If I disable IDM from browsers it will simply stop capturing any downloads from that particular browser and it will still be capturing software updates, wouldn't it ?